# The customized triggers will not get fired when RavenDB updates the docs through build in replication mechanism

Tags: replication, ravendb

1. There are two RavenDb (A and B)
2. A and B have enable the Replication bundle .(A is masterdb, B is slaveDb)
3. B have customized trigger deployed).

But customized triggers will not get fired when RavenDB updates the docs through build in replication mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

That is by design. Triggers are not called during replication